# Node.js async callback factory

Tags: node.js, api, rest, express

I'm developing a **RESTful API** with Node.js, Express and MySql. No ORM used.

I want to reuse as much code as possible in order to handle requests for resources.

I'm going to implement a **callback factory** and I'd like to hear from you about my approach.

### api.js

It is the main application file.

```js
'use strict';

var
  http = require('http'),
  express = require('express'),
  app = express(),

  env = app.get('env'),
  config = require('./config')[env],
  pool = require('./pool')(config.database), /* node-mysql pool */

  people = require('./routes/people')(pool); /* route handlers for people resource */

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(app.router);

app.get('/people', people.findAll); /* middleware handling request for the resource */

http.createServer(app).listen(8000);
```

### routes/people.js

It is the file containing code to handle requests for `/people`resource.

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  var
    async = require('async'),
    CallbackFactory = require('../CallbackFactory'),
    people = {};

  people.findAll = function (req, res, next) {
    async.waterfall(
      [
        CallbackFactory.createCallback('getPoolConnection', pool),
        CallbackFactory.createCallback('lastQuery', 'SELECT * FROM person'),
        CallbackFactory.createCallback('json', res)
      ],
      CallbackFactory.getCallback('next', next);
    );
  };

  return people;
};
```

### CallbackFactory.js

The module exports the `createCallback` method only.

The first argument to `createCallback` is always the callback name.
Other arguments are specific to the callback to create.

```js
'use strict';

var
  factoryMethods: {
    getPoolConnection: function (pool) {
      return function (callback) {
        pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
          callback(err, connection);
        };
      };
    },
    lastQuery: function (sql, values) {
      return function (connection, callback) {
        connection.query(sql, values, function (err, result) {
          connection.release();
          callback(err, result);
        });
      };
    },
    json: function (res) {
      return function (result, callback) {
        res.json(result);
        callback();
      };
    },
    next: function (next) {
      return function (err) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
      };
    },
  };

module.exports = {
  createCallback: function () {
    var
      args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
      name = args.shift();

    return factoryMethods[name].apply(null, args);
  }
};
```

### Conclusion

I googled and searched SO in order to find approaches that are useful to code reuse.
I didn't find anything. Maybe it is not the correct/best approach. **What do you think about it?**

Comment: I think it's also a matter of personal preference. I find it difficult to understand what `people.findAll` actually does, because of the added layer of abstraction (esp since your callback factory methods are quite generic). I tend to re-use *some* code if it makes the overall code easier to understand.

Comment: Great idea! I'd get headache implementing this - I'd rather write a code generator for this, though I hate duplicated code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the wrong track here. Callback factory is not a common pattern because it's adding a layer of abstraction without reducing complexity in any way. Phrased differently, think of async.waterfall as already providing the abstraction layer that you're looking for. Or, if you like named functions, that I recommend [async.auto](https://github.com/caolan/async#auto), which also automatically determines which functions can operation in serial and parallel based on the dependencies you specify.

I would recommend having async.waterfall or async.auto call your functions directly. If you want additional abstraction and less code, use an ORM like Sequelize. But I see your factory complicating understanding your code for anyone else who comes along later.

Comment: My primary concern is about avoiding repetition. So, you suggest me to encapsulate an async.waterfall or async.auto instead?

Comment: Yes, I would suggest using functions rather than factories for encapsulation. I would take a look at the Express or Mocha code bases for models. For a counterexample, here is how Sequelize implements the DAO Factory pattern: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/dao-factory.js

Comment: I followed your suggestion to use an ORM. I tried Persistence, Sequelize and Bookshelf and decided to use Bookshelf. Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/adriano-di-giovanni/7739383) of my first attempt.